# How to return a DOM's element with a handleClick function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and I was trying to return a simple Hello World to my DOM when I click the button.

Also there's no return error in console, and my console.log() is returning the right value when I click.

```
const Button = () => {

  function handleCLick() {
    console.log('Active')
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleCLick}>Clique aqui</button>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return <Button />
};

export default App;
```

Comment: hint: Use state in react

Comment: Where is the returned text meant to go?

Answer (score 0):

Return to where? The browser's event handling code is calling `handleClick`. Your code is nowhere near where the return value gets passed to.

If you want to display some content in response to a click event then:

- Use the `useState` hook to create a state
- Change the state using the click event handler
- Use some logic to return different content from the component based on the value of the state

This is covered [in the React manual](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add state - in this simple example we're just updating the `h1` element.
2. Move the handler from the button to the parent component, and have that pass the handler down to the `Button` component so that when it's clicked, that function is called.
3. When the handler is called update the state, and the component will render again, and `h1` will have the updated value.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  
  // Initialise your state
  const [h1, setH1] = useState('Nothing to see here.');
  
  // Set a new state when the handler is called
  function handleClick() {
    setH1('Hello World');
  }

  // Pass the handler function to `Button`
  // in its props. `h1` will contain the state,
  // and will be updated when the state changes
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{h1}</h1>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
  
}

// `Button` accepts the `handleClick` function
// and calls it when it's clicked
function Button({ handleClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleClick}
    >Clique aqui
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not wrapping your app into render, following this code

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);


const Button = () => {

  function handleCLick() {
    console.log('Active')
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleCLick}>Clique aqui</button>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return <Button />
};

root.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <App />
    </StrictMode>
  );

export default App;
```

Comment: The rendering is, presumably, taken care of by whatever is importing `App`. Your answer doesn't address the question of dealing with the return value of `handleCLick` at all.